# Measuring Production Cycle time in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

Please see the image below

[Production process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mbrW.png)

I have a production process with four work centers. Between each is WIP.  When starting the simulation I inject partially assembled product into each WIP queue.  I want to measure the total production cycle time for those products starting from the initial source.  When I run the current model, I get an error on the timeMeasureEnd because of the products that start in WIP mid production.  Is there a way I can have the initial WIP items bypass the timeMeasureEnd to so the cycle time is based on products that run through the complete line.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of timeMeasureStart and timeMeasureEnd blocks, you can just add parameters inside your Product agent called `startTime`, `endTime` and `cycleTime` of type double. And a parameter called `wip` of type boolean with default value `false`. To avoid the WIP's, whenever you inject the agents in the middle of the process, set `agent.wip=true;`

Whenever a product starts the process, set `agent.startTime= time()`, Whenever the process ends, type `agent.endTime=time()` and

```
if (agent.wip==false){
agent.cycleTime=agent.endTime-agent.startTime;
}
```

This will give you the cycle time.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If you see the image above, i used a selectOutput before the timeMeasureEnd... your agent needs a boolean variable for instance called "validCycle" that will take the value false if it enters through the enter block and true if it enters through the source block.

then the selectOutput will have the condition `agent.validCycle==true`

Comment: Thanks Felipe - enjoyed you last Anylogic Webinar before the holiday.